# Using Jones Matrices for HWP operation

Tags: optics, photons

I think this is a simple question but I cant seem to find helpful answers on the net.

Anyway; I have a HWP that takes Horizontally polarized light to Diagonally polarised light;

ie; $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\       1 & -1 \      \end{array} } \right]=B$

I want to show confirm to myself that it takes left circularly polarized (lcp) light to rcp light (I think this is what is does).

However if I calculate $B\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1\\       i \      \end{array} } \right]$, I get

$\frac{1}{2} \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   1+i \\       1-i \      \end{array} } \right]$ .

Can someone please either tell me what I have done wrong or clarify that this last result is rcp light.

Thankyou.

Comment: *"but I cant seem to find helpful answers on the net."* - [Phase retarders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_calculus#Phase_retarders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculation is correct. Simply rewrite it a little as follows:

$$\frac{1}{2} \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   1+i \\       1-i \      \end{array} } \right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}\exp\left(i\,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\\exp\left(-i\,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\end{array}\right)$$

Now you're missing the following fact: polarization states are unchanged by pure phase scaling. So, you still have the same polarization if you multiply both elements of your vector by a phase factor $e^{i\,\theta},\,\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. So, multiply both factors by $\exp\left(-i\,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ and see what happens. You should get something more recognizable as the orthogonal circularly polarization state.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually to the same conclusion after much thought - but it is very helpful to have my intuition confirmed.

Comment: @LewisHoward After I wrote the answer, I realized this was what AlfredCentauri's comment was about. That one was a bit cryptic for me.